# Error when using jade n node express to retrieve data from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */ 
router.get('/', function(req, res) { 
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/products',function(req, res){ 
   var db = req.db;
   var collection = db.get('products123'); //products123 is your collection in database
   console.log(collection)
   collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){ 
       res.render('products.jade', { "apps" : docs });
   });
}); 

module.exports = router;
```

And error:

> C:\node\cmpe226\views\products.jade:4 2| block content 3| each item, i in docs > 4| li item1 = #item.COMPANY expected "indent", but got "newline"
>
> Error: C:\node\cmpe226\views\products.jade:4
>       2| block content
>       3|   each item, i in docs
>   4|   li item1 = #item.COMPANY

any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your own question. Do not post code in comments. Try `console.log( docs )` in the appropriate place. There are many parts not even in your listing that could be the problem. Work out which one first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Simple jade-**syntax** error in your template. [Check it](http://jade-lang.com/reference/).
2. In template if you res.render('templateName',{ apps: docs }), then do each item, idx **in apps not in docs**. Or render('templateName', { docs: docs }) docs var now available in template.

   ```
   block content      
     if docs && docs.length > 0
       ul 
         each item, idx in docs
           li= item.COMPANY
     else 
       p nothing to show
   ```